# SSD not recognized in Windows 10 setup

Tags: windows, windows-10, ssd, installation, windows-installation

I bought a new Dell Vostro 5402, which came with a bloated and buggy Windows installation, so I want to perform a clean setup.

Problem is, after creating a bootable installation media with Microsoft's Media Creation Tool and starting up the setup, I get to the "[Where do you want to install Windows?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqwzt.png)" screen and it can't find the drive.

I've checked the internet for quite a while in search for a solution. Some said it's because of the USB 3 port, butmy laptop doesn't have any USB 2 ports, unfortunately. Other answers didn't really help. I tried going in troubleshoot mode and diskpart's list didn't show my drive either. The BIOS however does show it of course, and Windows currently boots normally.

I'm quite out of options here, and deperate to install a clean Windows 10 on my new laptop.

Comment: I have replaced hard drives with SSD and generally do not have issues. Is the SSD compatible with the Dell hardware?  Did you try the Dell Recovery USB Key?  New: Did you contact Dell Support?

Comment: I had this issue once and solved it by going into the Dell BIOS and changing the drive configuration to not be RAID 0. That then made the drive visible. Because I was using only one drive, changing that setting didn’t matter.

Comment: Based on the screenshot, you have enabled Legacy Mode (BIOS) mode in order to boot to the installation disk and your current Windows instal is UEFI.  That is the reason no disks are listed.  The simplest way around the problem you describe is to Reset Windows from within Windows.  It’s no longer necessary to boot into an installation environment to accomplish what you wants. Fresh Start will also accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most simple setting solved this issue.
In BIOS, go to Storage screen and pick AHCI/NVMe mode instead of RAID.

No idea why RAID is the default mode for a laptop with just one SSD.